# How to subscribe to ActiveMQ with ‘client-individual’ ack mode in PHP 7.1 or higher?

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, stomp

I’m trying to acknowledge a single message in ActiveMQ 5.15.9 message queue in Symfony 4 application. So far I used 3 stomp clients to achieve this:

- enqueue-dev bundle
- stomp-php bundle
- STOMP php extension (from PECL 2.0.2)

It seems like none of them supports change of ack mode. I’m trying to iterate through all messages from queue and acknowledge only some of them. I've tried many variations even using transactions, but no solution yet. This is possible in PHP 5.3.

### php-enqueue/enqueue-dev

While loop stops after first message, it doesn’t move on until I acknowledge current message. With reject method there is an option to requeue message, but ActiveMQ doesn’t support this flag.

```php
    use Enqueue\Stomp\StompConnectionFactory;

    $stompFactory = new StompConnectionFactory('stomp://127.0.0.1:61613?login=admin&password=admin');
    $context = $stompFactory->createContext();
    $messageQueue = $context->createQueue('foo.bar');
    $consumer = $context->createConsumer($messageQueue);
    $consumer->setAckMode('client-individual');

    while($msg = $consumer->receive(50)){
       $messages[]= $msg;
    }
```

### stomp-php

Same situation like in enqueue-dev.

```php
    use Stomp\Client;
    use Stomp\StatefulStomp;

    $client = new Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:61613');
    $client->setLogin('admin','admin');
    $client->getConnection()->setReadTimeout(1);
    $stomp = new StatefulStomp($client);
    $stomp->subscribe('foo.bar',null,'client-individual');

    while($msg = $stomp->read()) {
       $messages[] = $msg;
    }
```

### STOMP extension 2.0.2

I can get all messages without acknowledging them, but when I try to acknowledge a single one in the middle, all previous ones are being acknowledged as well. (which means it’s client ack mode). The same code works on php 5.3 and STOMP 1.0.9, ‘client-individual’ is supported and I can acknowledge a single message.

```php
    $stomp = new \Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613','admin','admin');
    $stomp->subscribe('foo.bar', array('ack' => 'client-individual'));
    while ($msg = $stomp->readFrame()) {
       $messages[] = $msg;
    }
    $stomp->ack($messages[1]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to put all messages that could not be acknowledged into a different queue instead? Otherwise you will basically be forced to loop endlessly. Also this would solve your issue with enqueue/stomp-php that reject with requeue is not supported. Instead you move the message to the new queue and acknowledge it.

Comment: Well, I want to leave these 'not-acknowledged' messages, because there's gonna be another funcionality that handles them. Messages in my queue differ by some custom property in header and depending of value, diffrent things happen to them in a diffrent time. So far I came up with acknowledging all of them in a loop and storing those 'other' messages in an array. After this loop, messages are being sent back to queue again. It's far from perfect, that's why I'm looking to make 'client-individual' work. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I recommend you look at the stream of STOMP frames in the environment where it works and then compare that to the stream of STOMP frames in the environment where it doesn't work. Any differences should be pretty easy to identify since STOMP frames are just text.

Comment: For what it's worth the fact that the same code works on PHP 5.3 and STOMP 1.0.9 and all you did was change the PHP and STOMP client version and not the broker version is a strong indication that the problem is not with the broker. That's why I removed the `activemq` tag from the question.